# How to improve performance of query for distinct suppliers in big sales table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I have two tables, one with store data:

```
              Table "public.store"
  Column   |          Type          | Modifiers
-----------+------------------------+-----------
 id        | integer                | not null
 hul_code  | character varying      |
 latitude  | numeric                |
 longitude | numeric                |
 name      | character varying(100) |
Indexes:
    "store_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "store-hlcode-idx" btree (hul_code)
```

Another with the sales data:

```
         Table "public.sale_data"
  Column   |       Type        | Modifiers
-----------+-------------------+-----------
 id        | integer           | not null
 hul_code  | character varying |
 partyname | character varying |
 rscode    | character varying |
 rsname    | character varying |
 cluster   | character varying |
 channel   | character varying |
 basepack  | character varying |
 total_16  | numeric           |
 total_17  | numeric           |
 total_18  | numeric           |
Indexes:
    "sale_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "hul-code-idx" btree (hul_code)
    "sd-bp-idx" btree (basepack)
    "sd-rscd-idx" btree (rscode)
```

The second table has over 11 million rows.

I'm trying to get the list of all stores which had items coming from a particular Regional Supplier (identified by `rscode`) by using a query like:

```
Select s.hul_code, s.name, s.latitude, s.longitude
from store s 
Where hul_code in 
  (Select Distinct(hul_code) as hulcode
   from sale_data
   where rscode='133955')
AND s.latitude is not null;
```

This query takes more than 1.5 to 2 seconds on average.

How to increase the speed of this query?

Comment: Did you try EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYZE? Is rscode really a string? You will get better performances with integers... No index on latitude? Also the DISTINCT is probably unnecessary since you use `IN`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Unfortunately rscode has to be a string since some of the values have `-` in them.

Comment: An index on `(rscode, hul_code)` might help.

Comment: More information on data distribution would help. How many distinct values in `rscode`? How many rows in table `store`? Is referential integrity between `sale_date.hul_code` and `store.hul_code` enforced (with a FK constraint)? How many distinct `hul_code` in `sale_data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For typical data distributions, emulating a [***loose index scan***](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) should be the magic trick for you.

Requires a multicolumn index to be fast:

```
CREATE INDEX ON sale_data(rscode, hul_code);
```

The variant with **correlated subquery** in the rCTE should be fastest for the simple case:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT min(hul_code) AS hul_code
   FROM   sale_data
   WHERE  rscode = '133955'    -- provide rscode here

   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT hul_code
           FROM   sale_data
           WHERE  rscode = '133955'     -- repeat rscode here
           AND    hul_code > c.hul_code
           ORDER  BY 1
           LIMIT  1
           )
   FROM   cte c
   )
SELECT s.hul_code, s.name, s.latitude, s.longitude
FROM   cte c
JOIN   store s USING (hul_code);
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

There may be faster alternatives for particular data distributions.

#### Asides:

`DISTINCT` *might* make sense for data distributions with very few rows per distinct `(rscode, hul_code)` (producing large numbers of resulting rows). But what you have doesn't make a lot of sense:

```
IN (Select Distinct(hul_code) as hulcode ... )
```

The column alias (`as hulcode`) is noise since `IN` ignores column names.

`DISTINCT` does *not* require parentheses. `(hul_code)` is interpreted as ROW constructor, short for `ROW(hul_code)`. The row wrapper *happens* to be stripped automatically for the single column in this case. But you might introduce complications for cases with multiple columns.

There is the Postgres variant `DISTINCT ON ()` which requires parentheses, but that's not used (nor needed) here. Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

But none of this makes a lot of sense with an `IN` construct, where you might just drop `DISTINCT` altogether. Better, yet, rewrite as:

```
SELECT s.hul_code, s.name, s.latitude, s.longitude
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT hul_code
   FROM   sale_data
   WHERE  rscode='133955'
   ) sd
JOIN  store s USING (hul_code);
```

.. in the unlikely case that you should have such a data distribution.

And your columns `rscode` seems to hold numeric data. If so, it should be a [numeric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html), not `varchar`.